# When i create a AutoLoad script i have an Invalid get Index 'runnig': (on base: 'null instance')

Tags: error-handling, game-engine, godot, autoload, gdscript

```
extends Control

onready var dialogue_box = $CanvasLayer/DialogueBox

var playing_intro : bool = false


func _ready():
    playing_intro = true
    if !dialogue_box.running:
        dialogue_box.start()
```

And i try to change AutoLoad name, but nothing happened.
My solution is not to use the AutoLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Script`s do not come with a **scenes** attached.

So when you Autoload your `Script` it won't come with the other `Node`s you had in the scene where you designed it.

In this case you are trying to access `$CanvasLayer/DialogueBox` which is not there because the Autoload is the `Script` not the **scene**.

---

But **scenes** can have `Script`s attached.

So add your **scene** (the `.tscn` or `.scn` file) as Autoload.

Then it should work.